# What this line doing? Django-template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Explain me please what this line doing:

```
<a href="{% url video.media.views.channel_browse slug=slug%}">Archie Channel</a>
```

Actually this:

```
{% url video.media.views.channel_browse slug=slug%}
```

I know that it give me URL, but what from, or how it is making this URL?

does this url depend from context? if it depend from context so which context - this where is this line or which gives `channel_browse` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `url` template tag uses the `reverse()` [function](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) to look up which [url dispatch line](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/) has a `name=channel_browse`, including if it needs to fill in `slug=whatever` because that particular url dispatch line has a `(?P<slug>.*)` argument in it that needs to be filled in order to recreate the actual url.

Here's a [complete explanation](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/13/how-django-processes-request/) of the whole request system.